How to Adjust Elevation and Azimuth Relative to the Original Route in 2D/3D Plot (lat, long, alt) in MATLAB?
I have a route represented by latitude, longitude, and altitude (LLA) values, and I want to adjust this route based on azimuth and elevation angles relative to the original path. This means the rotation should be performed around the original route’s direction, not around the global coordinate system axes.
Inputs:

Route: Latitude, longitude, and altitude values.
Azimuth: Desired relative angle to rotate around the original path’s vertical axis.
Elevation: Desired relative angle to rotate around the original path’s horizontal axis.

I converted the route’s points to ECEF (Earth-Centered, Earth-Fixed) coordinates using MATLAB’s built-in lla2ecef and ecef2lla functions. I then tried applying a rotation matrix around the Z-axis (azimuth) and Y-axis (elevation). However, I couldn’t get the correct transformation, as the rotation was performed relative to the global axes, not the original path.
Here’s the code I have so far:
function rotated_route = rotate_route_lla(lat, lon, alt, azimuth, elevation)
    % Convert azimuth and elevation to radians
    azimuth = deg2rad(azimuth);
    elevation = deg2rad(elevation);
    
    % Convert LLA to ECEF using MATLAB's built-in function
    [x, y, z] = lla2ecef([lat, lon, alt]);

    % Create rotation matrices
    % Rotation around Z-axis (azimuth)
    Rz = [cos(azimuth), -sin(azimuth), 0;
          sin(azimuth),  cos(azimuth), 0;
          0,             0,            1];

    % Rotation around Y-axis (elevation)
    Ry = [cos(elevation),  0, sin(elevation);
          0,              1, 0;
         -sin(elevation),  0, cos(elevation)];
     
    % Combined rotation matrix (first Y, then Z)
    R_total = Rz * Ry;
    
    % Combine coordinates into matrix form for rotation
    route_ecef = [x(:), y(:), z(:)]';
    
    % Apply the rotation
    rotated_ecef = R_total * route_ecef;

    % Extract rotated x, y, z
    x_rotated = rotated_ecef(1, :);
    y_rotated = rotated_ecef(2, :);
    z_rotated = rotated_ecef(3, :);
    
    % Convert rotated ECEF back to LLA using MATLAB's built-in function
    rotated_lla = ecef2lla([x_rotated(:), y_rotated(:), z_rotated(:)]);
    
    % Return the rotated route in LLA format
    rotated_route = rotated_lla;
end

My Problem:
I believe my approach applies the rotation matrices relative to the global axes, but I need to rotate the route relative to the original path. The goal is to rotate the points along the route according to the specified azimuth and elevation relative to the direction of the path itself.
Questions:

How can I adjust the rotation to be relative to the original path rather than around the global axes?
What is the correct method for rotating a path defined in LLA based on azimuth and elevation angles relative to the original path?
Are there better MATLAB functions or techniques for achieving this kind of transformation?

Example Route:
% Example route data (latitude, longitude, altitude)
lat = [32.08088, 32.08288, 32.08588];
lon = [34.78057, 34.78157, 34.78257];
alt = [100, 105, 110]; % Altitude in meters

% Desired azimuth and elevation for transformation
azimuth = 45; % in degrees
elevation = 30; % in degrees

% Rotate the route
rotated_route = rotate_route_lla(lat, lon, alt, azimuth, elevation);

MATLAB Functions Used:

lla2ecef: To convert from latitude, longitude, and altitude to Earth-Centered, Earth-Fixed coordinates.
ecef2lla: To convert from Earth-Centered, Earth-Fixed coordinates back to latitude, longitude, and altitude.

I’d appreciate any help with rotating the route relative to the original direction and ensuring the transformed route matches the specified azimuth and elevation angles.
